# Portable way of setting the windows urgent hint?

Tags: window, frames

I've seen links to X11 flag setting that sets the current windows urgent hint.

Is there a portable way to do this in Emacs? Or does it need to be handled per-platform?

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet from @arne-babenhauserheide's site for making the frame urgent in X11, while it works it's not portable.

```el
(defun my-frame-urgent-hint-set--for-x11 (frame arg &optional source)
  "Set the x11-urgency hint for the frame to arg:

- If arg is nil, unset the urgency.
- If arg is any other value, set the urgency.

If you unset the urgency, you still have to visit the frame to make the urgency setting disappear."
  (let* ((wm-prop "WM_HINTS")  ;; Constants.
         (wm-flag-urgent #x100)

         (wm-hints (append (x-window-property wm-prop frame wm-prop source nil t) nil))
         (flags (car wm-hints)))
    (setcar wm-hints
            (if arg
                (logior flags wm-flag-urgent)
              (logand flags (lognot wm-flag-urgent))))
    (x-change-window-property wm-prop wm-hints frame wm-prop 32 t)))

(defun my-frame-urgent-hint-set (&optional arg)
  "Mark the current Emacs frame as requiring urgent attention.

With a prefix argument which does not equal a boolean value of nil, remove the urgency flag
(which might or might not change display, depending on the window manager)."
  (interactive "P")
  (let*
      (
       (frame (selected-frame))
       (win-system (window-system frame)))
    (cond
     ((eq win-system 'x)
      (my-frame-urgent-hint-set--for-x11 frame (not arg)))
     ;; TODO, other platforms.
     (t
      (message "Urgent hint for window system %S unsupported" win-system)))))
```